# Using Google PhotosLibrary in C#

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using `c#` on Windows with `Google.Apis.PhotosLibrary.v1` and I'm wondering how to get all photos from google PhotosLibrary.

So far I could authenticate with the scope `PhotosLibraryService.Scope.PhotoslibraryReadonly`.

I'm able to get all `Albums` like this:

```
var albumsList = await Service.Albums.List().ExecuteAsync();
foreach (var item in albumsList.Albums)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Album title: " + item.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("Album ID: " + item.Id);

    await GetPhotos(item.Id);
}
```

But this only returns photos from a given Album.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `Google.Apis.PhotosLibrary.v1` was released in error, and has now been delisted from nuget, as C# is not currently supported. So it's likely that the library you're using simply doesn't contain the functionality you're looking for.

As you can see here: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/client-libraries
Only Java and PHP client libraries are currently available.

Comment: Well that's too bad :(

Comment: I know, sorry :(

Comment: Too late to help the original poster but this may help others, I've written a fully-featured .NET library https://github.com/f2calv/CasCap.Apis.GooglePhotos available as a NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/CasCap.Apis.GooglePhotos/